# How to sort text lines in C++ using The Alphanum Algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I would like to use The Alphanum Algorithm to sort some text lines contained in *.txt files.

I've seen this site:
http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html

And there's a *.cpp file that contains this algorithm.

But I don't know how to use it.

So let's say I have code like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{

    ifstream file;
    file.open("My_textfile.txt");

    [ALPHANUM SORTS My_textfile.txt --> don't know how to do it :( ]

    file.close();
    return 0;

}
```

Is there any simple way to perform sorting using this algorithm?

Best regards,
Mike

Comment: I don't see how this question can be labeled 'too broad' since it applied to the use of a specific library...

Comment: That's my first question ever here, so I could've expected that it would be marked as a bit inappropriate :)

Answer (score 1):

The .cpp is dependent on MFC, and is useless, since it does not come with the corresponding class definition.  You should use alphanum.hpp (it's a header-only library) if you want to use the algorithm in your project.

To sort, use the stl sort function.

Example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include "alphanum.hpp"

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> v;

  // fill array ...

  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), doj::alphanum_less<std::string>());

  //  v is sorted !

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see it now! I'm very grateful you answered my question. Thanks!